# Visualization in changed occupancy threshold case

Tags: rviz, octomap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Default value of Occupancy Threshold is 0.5. In my code, I changed it to 0.2 by using setOccupancyThres(0.2).

It works fine in Octree e.g. all nodes having probability greater 0.2 considered as occupied.

But in RVIZ, the nodes with probability less than 0.5 does not shown up.

I think, I have to changed value somewhere in octomap_rviz plugins ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277297/visualization-in-changed-occupancy-threshold-case/) by [tonyParker](https://answers.ros.org/users/15131/tonyparker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 377 on 2017-12-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been investigating this problem myself.
The short answer is yes, the octomap_rviz plugin does not seem to support this.

Looking at 'occupancy_grid_display.cpp', within 'incomingMessageCallback()':

```
if (octomap->isNodeOccupied(*it))
```

'isNodeOccupied()' looks up the log of the threshold which you are presumably setting.

Unfortunately, it seems the 'octomap' variable being referenced here is not the same as the one you are setting the threshold of. It is created from the message in the callback:

```
octomap::AbstractOcTree* tree = octomap_msgs::msgToMap(*msg);
    if (tree){
        octomap = dynamic_cast<OcTreeType*>(tree);
...
```

Seeing as there is no field in the message to carry the threshold data, I don't know how to solve your problem.

Of course, you could hard code the value, but it is hardly ideal.
Instead of isNodeOccupied()', use:

```
if (it->getOccupancy() > 0.5)
```

...where the value is between 0 and 1.

This applies to any other part which uses 'isNodeOccupied()', such as the neighbour checking.

---

Having said that, I have noticed that the Occupancy Map *does* show more cells as occupied. This could be down to it using a binary tree or something.

---

Originally posted by [cwalt](https://answers.ros.org/users/32038/cwalt/) with karma: 18 on 2017-12-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0